# Do first person shooters for console typically come with aiming help?

Tags: first-person-shooter

This is a rumour I heard somewhere on the internet I have little trouble in buying: aiming with console controllers does not sound too easy, especially when you need to go for "twitch shots".

Is it, however, actually true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, yes. Using analog sticks to aim is not as precise as using a mouse. So in several games, if you get your aim close enough to a target, the game will help by giving it a nudge in the right direction. Or if you do get on target and the target moves, it may adjust for you. (Depending on the game of course).

Some games of course have a lot of aim assist, others have only a little, and some will allow you to disable it completely.

Answer (score 1):

Different games offer different amounts of aim-assist, usually activated by holding down the "aim down the sights" button.  It ranges from full lock-on-and-track to just a gentle "nudge" towards center mass to none at all (or configurable).

In my experience, single-player games tend to have more aim-assist than multiplayer games, but not always.  The aim-assist greatly contributes to the unique feel of aiming in different games.

Answer (score 1):

Some games even allow you to turn these features off; however, I've found that they don't always turn them off completely, they just tone them down.  The Halo games for example employ a target assist that will "pull" your aim towards an enemy when they drift close enough to your crosshairs; however, if this feature is turned off, they'll still pull your crosshairs a bit, but it isn't as obvious.

Most console shooters, especially ones with heavy single player modes, will also employ an auto-center feature.  As you move forward, if you do not actively look in other directions, it will automatically cause your sights to drift towards the center of the horizon.  Typically you can turn this off as well, but it varies from game to game.

Answer (score 0):

I think that mosts of these games in single player mode it also give you some extra time for the enemies shoot at you because you are always a little bit slow for aiming and otherwise it would be imposible for beat any of them.